# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.sirat.data.network.WeatherApi cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: api, retrofit, dagger

I have tried to make a app. where I call 2 Api URL in network module object. But its show some error. I'm beginner in retrofit and dagger. How to solve this problem? and how can I call multiple api in my app.

Here is error.

> Blockquote
> @Module
> @InstallIn(`SingletonComponent`::class)
> object NetworkModule {

```
@Provides
fun retrofitHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}

@Provides
fun retrofitGsonConverter(): GsonConverterFactory {
    return GsonConverterFactory.create()
}

@Provides
fun retrofitInstance(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory
): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(WEATHER_BASE_URL_2)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .build()
}


@Provides
fun retrofitService(retrofit: Retrofit): WeatherApi {
    return retrofit.create(WeatherApi::class.java)
}

@Provides
fun retrofitInstanceSalah(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory
): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(SALAH_TIME_BASE_URL_2)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
        .build()
}


@Provides
fun retrofitServiceSalah(retrofit: Retrofit): WeatherApi {
    return retrofit.create(WeatherApi::class.java)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dagger doesn't understand you want to create two different objects, it only cares about the type of the object. You are providing same objects twice from perspective of dagger. You should use qualifiers to differentiate this kind of objects. Please read qualifier section in https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ .